# How to start an app in React Native(v0.66.4) on android startup?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to create implement a boot after the BOOT_COMPLETED action in a React Native(v0.66.4) project. But that doesn't seem to work, I've tried some solutions I've found on the internet, but for now without success. How can I achieve this?

AndroidManifest

:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
       <!-- start the application when the launch event happens -->
      <receiver
          android:name=".StartupReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="false"
          android:label="StartupReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

```
package com.example;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(launchIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `react-native-autostart` npm package?